# How can I create a maximum security prison, as a player character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Dnd3.5/pathfinder
We have been playing an epic level campaign for about three years time and amassed a considerable amount of loot, to the point where we plan to create some kind of magical stronghold.
Many of our enemies are high level mages and clerics of Lolth that could be worth more alive than dead. My plan is thus to create a maximum security prison that also serve as a source of magic energy, since we are at the point where gold is plenty but xp is not.

My plan is thus:
A prison shielded from etheral, teleportation and physical entrance. Using stronghold builders guide book the prison will be a single room cell with continous effect of mind fog and feeble mind, the walls will be force and in the center of the room will be a symbol of pain to keep prisoners and intruders pacified.
I plan on using the nipple clamps of exquisite pain and symbol of pain trick together with a self-resetting trap that casts distill joy on every occupant once per day. The prisoners will be held in check with shackles of silence.
What I lack right now is a method to keep them confined in permanent bubbles of force, and fed. The plan is that once a prisoner is put into the prison, there will be no contact with any one until the day of their release, each cell is suposed to be a self-contained unit keeping the occupant fed and waterd and in a state of blissful stupor, while at the same time milking them of ambrosia to fuel further magical creations.

My question is thus, how do I solve the problem of separete self contained force bubble cells and keeping the prisoners fed and unable to use spell like abilities, extrordinary at-will abilities and psionics?

Comment: Hey, can you clarify what edition of d&d you are asking about?

Comment: The 3.5 edition spell was called *Distill Joy* (Book of Exalted Deeds), not Distill Ambrosia, if we are talking about the same spell.

Comment: Given your phrasing, I'm guessing you're a player and not the DM.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125454/8610) and possibly even [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69187/8610).

Comment: Wouldn't that Ambrosia farming method be classified as torture, making your alignment not good any more and thus making the Ambrosia useless since you're no longer a good-aligned spellcaster? Anyone that knows what you're doing are also accomplices if they condone it and use the Ambrosia. Have you thought this through?

Comment: Perhaps, I could always distill liquid pain instead. I’m not picky.

Comment: Our party is neutral, so its either liquid pain or liquid joy. I’d recon joy is the lesser of two evils .

Comment: Liquid pain is easier to be farmed; you still will probably become evil but at least it won't be a deterrent to your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Stronghold Builders Guidebook has your solution.

This is a 3.0 book that was never updated, and thus is current for 3.5.

In this book are rules for making permanent magic architecture that affect a given room or rooms.

Build an imprisoning magic circle against (alignment) and circle it with a permanent wall of force powered by the room's architecture, all handily controllable with a focus object or structure, and you have your prison.

The room itself could be enchanted with a sustenance effect to cover the food and drink angle. (Sustenance is a psionic power that sustains a person without food or drink for 24 hours.)

To prevent all abilities, an anti magic shell might be ideal, but that would also prevent the sustenance effect. You could alternately ability drain or damage them down to where they are manageable.

After all, you only die if your constitution score hits zero, not your other stats.

> **Ability damage**: A temporary loss of 1 or more ability score
> points. Lost points return at a rate of 1 point per day unless noted
> otherwise by the condition dealing the damage. A character with
> Strength 0 falls to the ground and is helpless. A character with
> Dexterity 0 is paralyzed. A character with Constitution 0 is dead. *A
> Character with Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma 0 is unconscious.*

Though perhaps a simpler solution is to use the imprison spell or the crystallize power on them.

Oh, and don't forget the dimensional anchor effect! Might want to add a hallow effect if your enemies are mostly evil, which as a bonus allows rider effects to be attached and affect a large area.